# Does the standard guarantee that the total memory occupied by a std::vector scales as C+N*sizeof(T)?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, standards, sizeof

The C++ standard provides the guarantee that the content of a std::vector is stored contiguously. But does it states that the total occupied memory is:

```
S = C+N*sizeof(T)
```

where:

- S is the total size on the stack AND on the heap
- C is the total size on the stack: C =  sizeof(std::vector)
- N is the capacity of the vector
- T is the type stored

In other words, do I have the guarantee that there is no overhead per element ?
And if I have no such guarantee is there any reason ?

EDIT: to be clear, if I take the example of a `std::list`, it generally stores 2 extra pointers per element. So my question is: would a such implementation of a `std::vector` be standard-compliant ?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Can you elaborate?

Comment: While reallocating the memory, it normally double its size from the current. So in that case(worst case) scenario vector could hold almost the double size than on current number of elements.(2N*sizeof(T))

Comment: Typical allocation systems have hidden overhead, but usually it scales with the number of allocated blocks, not the size of allocated blocks.  Not sure what Mehrdad is getting at.

Comment: Note that N is not std::vector::size but std::vector::capacity. Do your remarks hold Mehrdad ?

Comment: @Vincent: Sure, but that's a bad implementation, wasting your memory for no reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you're so sure of things. but contrary to both the "in fact" and the emphasis in  your statement <<In fact there *cannot* be any "overhead per element">>, it's no big deal to implement `std::vector` with any overhead one desires. Such per element overhead cannot be placed within the visible part of the ordinary buffer, but it can be at either end of that part, or in separate places. the standard even allows gigabyte `bool` values, if so desired.

Comment: @Alf but then sizeof(bool) would be 1G :-) Generally though I agree. Nothing keeps an implementation from adding e.g. debug information before or after data, per element if deemed appropriate.

Comment: @Vincent Note that List does most likely violate the contiguity requirement, at least if you have 2 pointers overhead per element. (Unless you store the pointers outside of data which would be kindof silly. Yes, one could implement a list with pointers to elements in a contiguous array but that would violate element order.)

Comment: What do you mean by *memory* anyway? The code only every acquires *virtual* memory. Only when this is actually used will the kernel try to map that to actual *physical* memory. So, while `vector::capacity()` may be much larger than `vector::size()` and hence the 'memory' allocated much more than what you actually need, it may not be a problem, since it's mostly only virtual.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For there to be any such guarantee, the standard would have to pass the requirement on to the interface of the allocator. It doesn't, so there isn't.

In practice though, as a quality of implementation issue, you expect that memory allocators probably have a constant overhead per allocation but no overhead proportional to the size of the allocation. A counter-example to this would be a memory allocator that always uses a power-of-two-sized block regardless of the size requested. This would be pretty wasteful for large allocations, but not forbidden either as a user-defined allocator or even as the system allocator used by `::operator new[]`. It would create an overhead proportional to `N` on average, assuming that the vector capacities don't happen to fit nicely.

Leaving aside the allocator, I don't believe there's anything in the standard to say that the vector can't allocate (for example) an extra byte per element and use it to store some flags for who-knows-what purpose. As others have remarked, the contiguousness requirement means that those extra bytes cannot lie between the vector elements. They would have to be in a separate allocation or all together at one end of the allocation.

There's at least one good reason that the standard doesn't forbid implementations from "wasting" space by using it to store data used for operations not required by the standard -- doing so would rule out many debugging techniques!

Comment: It depends on how "total memory occupied" is defined. If it's defined by the total size given to `allocate` then this is an independent requirement.

Comment: For efficiency reasons, constant is unlikely: More memory is used to avoid fragmentation. Fibonacci and other low-fragmentation schemes.

Comment: @Mehrdad: well, it's not defined as exactly that since it's defined to include some memory on the stack. But sure, if it's defined something like that then there's still no explicit guarantee but it becomes harder to think of a plausible place for the overhead to go.

Comment: I don't think "it's defined to include some memory on the stack" is true. Consider `new vector<T>`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: it is defined exactly that way. Perhaps mistakenly so or perhaps the questioner realises that he is talking only about automatic variables. "C is the total size on the stack: C = sizeof(std::vector)". But even allowing for `new vector<T>`, the space in question still isn't part of "the total size given to `allocate`", so with suitable adjustment my point to Mehrdad stands I think. I guess you could go `std::allocator<std::vector<T>>::allocate` followed by `emplace` just to get it all under one allocator.

Comment: Your interesting deliberation about the 2^n allocator is also semantically challenging: What is considered the "total occupied memory" of the vector? If it is what the vector thinks it has (i.e. its reported capacity), your example is not valid because the vector will assume that it got no more than the requested memory. The _vector_ is free to allocate more, but since it's then its capacity it is no overhead. Overhead of the allocation mechanism is not in the realm of the vector. (This may be what Mehrdad wanted to say.) The 4k memory page for the process is also not the vector's business.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: right, Mehrdad's comment prompted me to think further for an at least vaguely plausible way that the vector itself could introduce an overhead proportional to N. I've yet to think of a good use for those flags, but "I dunno, debugging or something" is enough to motivate allowing it and answer the "is there any reason" part of the question, I think.

Comment: @SteveJessop I agree with debugging. Count operator[] calls per elem, it's not even inconceivable.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have the guarantee that there is no overhead per element?

Does the standard prohibit it? No.
But would you ever expect to see this in practice? No.

The rule of contiguous data storage and the complexity requirements of vector growth mean that the only possible way for a non-constant-sized data block to be part of the vector would be if it were emplaced directly before the dynamically-allocated element data, or somewhere else entirely. There is no guarantee that this doesn't happen, but, quite simply, no implementation does it because it would be entirely ridiculous and serve no purpose whatsoever.

> Does it states that the total occupied memory is:
>
> ```
> S = C+N*sizeof(T)
> ```

There may be other data members of the vector itself (what you've inaccurately deemed to be "on the stack"), increasing the object's size in constant terms.

Comment: Just for information, in what part of memory are stored the elements which make the result of sizeof(T) (for example often 3 pointers for a std::vector): static, stack or heap ?

Comment: @Deduplicator: That passage refers to direct members of the vector, whose combined size must be constant, as is the case with any type. Adding `random+42` bytes would require dynamic allocation, which is covered by the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The standard gives no guarantee, afaics. But the requirement that the elements be stored contiguously makes it likely that there is no *per element* overhead. The whole data must be in a memory area which was allocated in one piece. @aschepler remarked correctly though that typical free store implementations have a (constant) overhead per allocation unit, typically a size variable or an end pointer.

Additionally there may be some padding overhead, e.g. an allocation unit will probably span multiples of the natural word size on a machine. And then the OS call will likely reserve a whole memory page to the program, even if you allocate only 1 byte. Whether you consider that as overhead or not is a matter of taste (from the outside yes, from the inside of the program no; and of course subsequent vectors or resize()s dine from the same page).

So at least it's *CM + CV + N*sizeof(T),* CM and CV being the overhead in the vector (not necessarily on the stack, as Lighness said) and CM the overhead of the memory management.

Comment: Why doesn't he always allocate a second block of size C? It's insane, but there's no guarantee he won't do so.

Comment: -1 re "But the requirement that the elements be stored contiguously implies that there is no per element overhead." is wrong. there is no requirement that a `std::vector` stores all its state in the user-visible part of the main items buffer.

Comment: @Alf: Strictly spoken true. I changed to "likely" ;-). It excludes pathological implementations through list etc.

Comment: @Deduplicator because it's not guaranteed to be contiguous. In fact, with typical implementations it's guaranteed to be _not_ contiguous (because of the intervening alloc block size information).

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Sorry, I'm not quite sure. Why would it matter whether the additional memory the implementation wastes just for fun is continuous to anything else?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Oh, I misread your comment. Thought you suggested to implement resize() by allocating the next block _as extension_ of data, but you mean a totally unrelated block. Yes, Steve Jessup brought up debugging -- one could count operator[] calls per elem or whatever for example.

Answer (score 0):

No, the implementation characteristics you suggest would not be standard compliant.  The STL specifies that a `std::vector` support appending individual elements in *amortized constant time*.

In order for the amortized cost of inserting an element to be O(1), the size of the array must increase in at least a geometric progression when it is reallocated (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)).  A geometric progression means that if the size of the array was `N`, the new size after reallocation must be `K * N`, for some `K > 1`.  The choice of `K` is implementation dependent.

To find out how much space a `std::vector` has allocated, call `std::vector::capacity()`.  With regard to overhead per element, in the best case the `capacity() == size()`.  In the worst case `capacity() == K * (size() - 1)`.

If you must ensure that your vector is absolutely no larger than it has to be, you can call `std::vector::reserve()` if you know exactly how large your `std::vector` will be.  You may also call `std::vector::resize()` (or `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` in C++11) after you are done adding elements to reduce the amount of memory reserved.

Comment: In the question, `N` already is the capacity of the vector and not the size.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, it seems I misinterpreted the OP's question.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Although the OP also claims that his specification has no overhead per element, which seemed natural to me to interpret to mean data elements (rather than the entire allocated capacity).